# SwiftUI dismiss keyboard when tapping segmentedControl

Tags: ios, swiftui, resignfirstresponder

I have a TextField in SwiftUI that needs to use a different keyboard depending on the value of a @State variable determined by a SegementedControl() picker.

How can I dismiss the keyboard (like send an endEditing event) when the user taps a different segment?  I need to do this because I want to change the keyboard type and if the textField is the responder, the keyboard won't change.

I have this extension:

```
extension UIApplication {
    func endEditing() {
        sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
    }
}
```

And I can do something like

```
UIApplication.shared.endEditing()
```

But I don't know where or how to call this when the user taps a different segment.

I have tried putting a tapGesture on the Picker and the keyboard does dismiss,  but the tap does not pass through to the picker so it does not change.

Code snippet here:

```
@State private var type:String = "name"
```

.
.
.

```
Form {
    Section(header: Text("Search Type")) {
        Picker("", selection: $type) {
            Text("By Name").tag("name")
            Text("By AppId").tag("id")
        }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
    }

    Section(header: Text("Enter search value")) {
        TextField(self.searchPlaceHolder, text: $searchValue)
            .keyboardType(self.type == "name" ? UIKeyboardType.alphabet : UIKeyboardType.numberPad)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Attach a custom `Binding` to the `Picker` that calls `endEditing()` whenever it is set:

```
Section(header: Text("Search Type")) {
    Picker("", selection: Binding(get: {
        self.type
    }, set: { (res) in
        self.type = res
        UIApplication.shared.endEditing()
    })) {
        Text("By Name").tag("name")
        Text("By AppId").tag("id")
    }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
}
```

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks

Answer (score 7):

### Update since iOS 13 / iPadOS 13 was released.

Since there is now support for multiple windows in one app you need to loop through the UIWindows and end editing one-by-one.

```
UIApplication.shared.windows.forEach { $0.endEditing(false) }
```

Answer (score 2):

**SwiftUI 2.0**

Now it can be done in more elegant way, with `.onChange` (actually it can be attached to any view, but at `TextField` looks appropriate, by intention)

```
TextField("Placeholder", text: $searchValue)
    .keyboardType(self.type == "name" ? UIKeyboardType.alphabet : UIKeyboardType.numberPad)
    .onChange(of: type) { _ in
        UIApplication.shared.endEditing()   // << here !!
    }
```

**SwiftUI 1.0+**

There are much similar to above approaches

a) requires `import Combine`...

```
TextField("Placeholder", text: $searchValue)
    .keyboardType(self.type == "name" ? UIKeyboardType.alphabet : UIKeyboardType.numberPad)
    .onChange(of: type) { _ in
        UIApplication.shared.endEditing()
    }
    .onReceive(Just(type)) { _ in
        UIApplication.shared.endEditing()   // << here !!
    }
```

b) ... and not

```
TextField("Placeholder", text: $searchValue)
    .keyboardType(self.type == "name" ? UIKeyboardType.alphabet : UIKeyboardType.numberPad)
    .onReceive([type].publisher) { _ in
        UIApplication.shared.endEditing()   // << here !!
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

For SwiftUI 3 use FocusState and .focused(…)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).