# SwiftUI TextEditor how Hide Keyboard

Tags: swiftui, text-editor

I have à problem with TextEditor, I cannot hide the Keyboard after editing my text on the Texteditor.

```
    @State var monTexte: String = "
var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
                .frame(height :15)
                .clipped()
            Text("Project ")
                .font(Font.system(size: 39.00))              
               .fontWeight(.black)
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .padding(.all, 16.0)
                .clipped()
            
            TextEditor(text: $monTexte)
                .keyboardType(.alphabet)
                .font(.subheadline)
                .padding(.horizontal)
                .font(Font.system(size: 38.00))
                .frame(minWidth: 10, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 10, maxHeight: 200, alignment: .topLeading)
                .border(Color.black)
                .clipped()
}
}
}
```

I’ve found a method to hide the keyboard using a textfield but not using a TextEditor
Coule you help me please

Comment: How do you define moment of *after editing*, ie. at which event you want to hide keyboard?

Comment: with a specific button or using the key return on the keyboard (for example), but and didn’t find the function to hide the keyboard

Comment: Keybord Return in TextEditor makes new line (it is not a TextField), but for some button you can use approach like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58349955/swiftui-dismiss-keyboard-when-tapping-segmentedcontrol.

Answer (score 3):

I found this worked adequately for me. It's pure SwiftUI, without having to resort to UIKit.

```
struct TestView: View {
    @State private var response = ""
    @FocusState private var responseIsFocussed: Bool // dismiss response editor keyboard when hit Return

    var body: some View {
        TextEditor(text: $response)
            .focused($responseIsFocussed)
            .onReceive(response.publisher.last()) {
                if ($0 as Character).asciiValue == 10 { // ASCII 10 = newline
                    responseIsFocussed = false // unfocus TextEditor to dismiss keyboard
                    response.removeLast() // remove newline at end to prevent retriggering...
                }
            }
    }
}
```

The `.focused()` modifier on the view triggers attaches a trigger to the TextEditor to enable you to programmatically focus (show) or unfocus (dismiss) the keyboard. And the `.onReceive()` captures key entry; it checks whether the last char entered in the string is a newline (ASCII 10), and if so triggers the *un*focus. Its important to immediately remove this Return/newline from the end of the string, otherwise it can keep triggering...

Caveat: this only triggers off the **last** char; if you edit the string and move the cursor midway and hit Return, nothing will happen (which actually behaves somewhat intuitively, IMO...)

Answer (score 2):

Thank you "Asperi" it's works using the code below :

````
var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
                .frame(height :15)
                .clipped()
            Text("Project ")
                .font(Font.system(size: 39.00))              
               .fontWeight(.black)
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .padding(.all, 16.0)
                .clipped()
                        HStack {
                Spacer()
                Button("Close Keyboard") {
                    UIApplication.shared.endEditing()

                }.font(Font.system(size: 20))
                .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                
            }.clipped()
            TextEditor(text: $monTexte)
                .keyboardType(.alphabet)
                .font(.subheadline)
                .padding(.horizontal)
                .font(Font.system(size: 38.00))
                .frame(minWidth: 10, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 10, maxHeight: 200, alignment: .topLeading)
                .border(Color.black)
                .clipped()
}
}
} 

//----------------------------------------------------//
// Masquer le clavier
//----------------------------------------------------//
extension UIApplication {
    func endEditing() {
        sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use toolbar. This way you won't break new line logic.
Suppose you have 2 TextEditors:

```
VStack {
    TextEditor(text: $subjectText)
       .focused($focusField, equals: .subject)
     TextEditor(text: $messageText)
       .focused($focusField, equals: .message)
}
  .toolbar {
      ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard) {
         Spacer()
         Button(focusField == .subject ? "Next" : "Done") {
            if focusField == .subject {
               focusField = .message
            } else {
               UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
               focusField = nil
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

Where

```
@FocusState private var focusField: Field?
enum Field: Hashable {
    case subject
    case message
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like protspace, I prefer to allow the user to create new lines in the text editor. I find [this solution from designcode.io](https://designcode.io/swiftui-handbook-hide-keyboard) really straightforward:

```
extension View {
func hideKeyboard() {
    let resign = #selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder)
    UIApplication.shared.sendAction(resign, to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
  }
}
```

And then just attach this to the relevant part of your view:

```
.onTapGesture {
        hideKeyboard()
}
```